# converting complex statement using which()

Tags: r, functional-programming

How do I simplify the following code using a which() statement:

```
install.packages("ISLR")
library(ISLR)
Auto <- na.omit(Auto)
q <- numeric(0);
for (i in seq(names(Auto))) {
  if ((class(eval(parse(text=paste('Auto$',names(Auto)[i],sep="")))) == "numeric") &
   (length(table(eval(parse(text=paste('Auto$',names(Auto)[i],sep=""))))) > 15)) {
    q <- cbind(q,i)}
}
```

This is more than just multiple if-then statements. I'm determining something about the class and distribution of the data in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to grab the information about each column in your data frame:

```
classes <- unlist(lapply(Auto, class))
num.unique <- unlist(lapply(Auto, function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

Then, you can find the indices of numeric variables with more than 15 elements easily:

```
which(classes == "numeric" & num.unique > 15)
#          mpg displacement   horsepower       weight acceleration 
#            1            3            4            5            6
```

Comment: q <- which(unlist(lapply(Auto, class)) == "numeric" &
             unlist(lapply(Auto, function(x) length(unique(x)))) > 15)
Works great! thx

Comment: Sure, or `which(unlist(lapply(Auto, function(x) class(x) == "numeric" & length(unique(x)) > 15)))`